# How can I replace for loop by sapply or apply in a function loading spatial data from MySQL

Tags: r

I am loading polygon data from MySQL in R. I have written a function that works fine.  I'm hoping to replace my messy loop with something faster(apply or tapply?)

This is for AWS ubuntu server , running  MySQL server 5.7 and R programming

```
# INSTALLING AND LOADING NECESSARY PACKAGES
packages = c("RMySQL","rgeos");
for (package in packages) {
  if (package %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"] == FALSE) {
    install.packages(package);
  }
}

lapply(packages, require, character.only = TRUE)

options(rds = list(
  "host" = "avanse-instance.cqzqewynskco.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com",
  "port" = 3306,
  "user" = [user],
  "password" = [password]
))

LoadBuildings <- function() {
  # Connect to the MySQL database
  db <- dbConnect(MySQL(), dbname = "watsan", host = options()$rds$host, 
                  port = options()$rds$port, user = options()$rds$user, 
                  password = options()$rds$password)
  # Construct the fetching query
  query1 <- paste("SELECT ST_AsText(geom_building) FROM building where zone = 'Charrier_Vertieres_1';")
  query2 <- paste("SELECT * FROM building where zone = 'Charrier_Vertieres_1';")
  # Submit the fetch query and disconnect
  polyg <- dbGetQuery(db, query1)
  dt <- dbGetQuery(db, query2)
  dbDisconnect(db)

  spdf <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(readWKT(polyg[1, ]), dt[1, ], match.ID = FALSE)
  for (i in 2:nrow(polyg)){
    spdf <- rbind(spdf, SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(readWKT(polyg[i, ]), dt[i, ], match.ID = FALSE))
  }
  return(spdf)
}
```

Are there any suggestions for other ways to solve this, perhaps using apply or tapply? Thanks and sorry for the nasty code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `for` loop isn't the cause of any slowness.  It's building your dataframe with `rbind` that will slow you down. Try using this instead

```
spdf <- vector("list", nrow(polyg))
for (i in seq_along(spdf)){
  spdf[[i]] <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(readWKT(polyg[i, ]), dt[i, ], match.ID = FALSE)
}

spdf <- do.call("rbind", spdf)
```

Alternatively, you can use this next bit of code.  But I would be surprised to see much difference in performance.

```
spdf <- 
  lapply(seq_len(nrow(polyg)),
         function(i){
           SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(readWKT(polyg[i, ]), dt[i, ], match.ID = FALSE)
         })
spdf <- do.call("rbind", spdf)
```